# Create a Azure PostgreSQL schema using terraform on a Azure PostgreSQL Database

Tags: postgresql, terraform, database-schema

I am able to create a `azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server` and `azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_database` using terraform.

I am not able to create a schema using TF but not able to get much help on documentation.
I also checked https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cyrilgdn/postgresql/latest/docs/resources/postgresql_schema

but that uses a different provider. I am not sure what am I missing here.

This is the TF template which creates the Azure PostgreSQL server and DB -

```
module "common_modules" {
  source = "../modules/Main"
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

locals {
  #Construct Tag Data for Resource
  resourceTags = {
    environment  = var.environment
    createdBy    = var.createdBy
    managedBy    = var.managedBy
    colorBand    = var.colorBand
    purpose      = var.purpose
    lastUpdateOn = formatdate("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss ZZZ", timestamp())
    }
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "postgreSQL" {
  name                = var.postgreSQL
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.ckeditorResorceGroup

  administrator_login           = var.postgreSQLAdmin
  administrator_password        = var.password

  sku_name   = "B_Standard_B1ms"
  version    = "13"
  storage_mb = 32768

  backup_retention_days             = 7
  geo_redundant_backup_enabled      = false
  tags                              = local.resourceTags
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_database" "postgreSQLDB" {
  name              = var.postgreSQLDB
  server_id         = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.postgreSQL.id
  collation         = "en_US.utf8"
  charset           = "utf8"
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_firewall_rule" "postgreSQLFirewallRule" {
  name                = "allow_access_to_azure_services"
  server_id           = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.postgreSQL.id
  start_ip_address    = "0.0.0.0"
  end_ip_address      = "0.0.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

have a look at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cyrilgdn/postgresql or https://github.com/cyrilgdn/terraform-provider-postgresql

usable, but you need network connectivity to resolve names (azure private dns zone) and to connect with postgresql flexible server. The terraform code should run in same vnet like flexi server.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33557663)